# SQL Select Omitting Multiples

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, sql-order-by

I have two (2) tables - Account and Order. Each row of the Order column contains an Account ID, which links it to a particular Account in the Account table. Each Account can have any number (zero-n) Orders. I've LEFT OUTER JOINED the two on the Account ID, so the table looks like this:

```
|Account ID|Account Data|Order A/C ID|Order ID|Order Date|
----------------------------------------------------------
|A001      |Blah blah   |A001        |O001    |Some date |
|A001      |Blah blah   |A001        |O002    |Some date |
|A002      |Blah blah   |A002        |O003    |Some date |
|A003      |Blah blah   |Null        |        |          |
|A004      |Blah blah   |A004        |O005    |Some date |
|A004      |Blah blah   |A004        |O006    |Some date |
|A005      |Blah blah   |A005        |O007    |Some date |
|A005      |Blah blah   |A005        |O008    |Some date |
|A005      |Blah blah   |A005        |O009    |Some date |
```

But I want to have the table only show one row per Account, by some field of the Order (say, for each Order for an Account, choosing the most recent one by the Order Date field and only displaying that one).

The table also has to show rows where there is no Order for the Account, as well.

The idea, of course, is to get a table showing, for each Account, its latest Order or, if there is no order for that Account, then nulls in the Order fields.

Oh, for what it's worth, SQL Server 17.8.

Comment: What if you have more than one order with the most resent date for the current account?

Comment: It's actually a date/time, down to the thousands of a second. The chance of two orders with the exact same time can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rank](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to rank the orders for account and then select first rank orders, something like below -

```
Select * from
(
    Select 
     A.AccountId,
     A.AccountData,
     o.OrderAcctId,
     o.OrderId,
     o.OrderDate,
     Rank() Over (Partition by A.AccountId order by O.OrderDate) as Rnk
    From Account 
    Left Join Order O on A.AccountId = o.OrderAcctId
) Query 
Where Rnk = 1
```